# Embedded code to be displayed on click event of button

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, embed, buttonclick

I have a embedded code which displays yahoo chart

the embedded code is -

```
<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D%5Ensebank;range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>
```

I want this embedded code to be displayed when I click on the display button.

Please suggest the relevant javascript.

I tried something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ln(){
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D%5Ensebank;range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>'();
  }
</script>
<input type=button style="background-color:#123742; color:#FFFFFF ; font-weight:bold; font-size:15" name=Button2 value=Calculate onClick=ln();></td></tr>
```

by referring to a code found on the internet but is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing onClick code with JavaScript add embedded code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758099/changing-onclick-code-with-javascript-add-embedded-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line need to be edited:

```
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed ....</embed>'();
```

To:

```
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed ....</embed>';
```

the parantheses are not supposed to be there, because the string is not a function.

Create a div with the said id first then add the content to it:

```
<div id="looknorth"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ln(){
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed....></embed>';
  }
</script>
<input type="button" value="Show Chart" onClick="ln();" />
```

Comment: also i want to know what is to be replaced at space of 'looknorth'

Comment: tried changing the code but still giving error saying 'document.getElementById(...)' is a null or not an object

Comment: See my updated code. you need to add a div with the ID looknorth

Comment: it worked.   one more doubt in embeded code i have a variable which is script ticker symbol  symbol%3D%5Ensebank   here "nsebank" i want to make it variable whose value is selected from drop downmenu what code i shall change

Comment: <select size="1" name="D1">
<option value="nsei" selected>Nifty</option>
<option value="bsen">Sensex</option>
</select><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="B1" onClick=ln();></p>

Comment: i want the variable in embeded code which gets replaced with nsei or bsen before displaying embeded code on click help @Ibu

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, you should create a seperate question for your new request

Comment: created new question at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758794/add-variable-in-embeded-object-to-be-displayed-onclick