# adding variable in embeded code with dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, html, variables, embed

i am trying to make a cript which displays a embeded code of yahoo graph

embeded script is

```
<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D^nsebank;range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>
```

in this script i want the value of state=symbol=^nsebank   (^nsebank) to be taken from a drop down menu list and then when click  on calculate button it displays the embeded code

i have written the code as follows -

```
<div id="looknorth"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ln(){
D11=parseFloat(D1.value);
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D"+D11+";range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>';} </script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1  width="400">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#123742; font-size:12 ; font-weight:bold">
<font color="#FFFFFF">Compounding</font>
<td>&nbsp;<br />
<select name="D1">
<option value="^nsei">Annually</option>
<option value="^bsen">Half Yearly</option>
</select>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ALIGN="center">
<input type=button style="background-color:#123742; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:15" name=calculate value=Calculate onClick=ln();>
</table>
```

The script is not working please help me in fixing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tfw.debugger:

1. @parseFloat(D1)—string (the option value) doesn't provide a Number that can be parsed.  The result that ends up in your embed tag is “NaN” and not the provided option value;  The value provided in the second option didn't work for me, the first one did, so I would check on what you're sending in there.
2. I noticed a '%3D' entity in your string which [unescapes](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) to an equals symbol.  Check the syntax of the variable you're sending in.  For example `state=symbol%3D'+D11+';range=1d;…` is what you have.

   - This translates to `state=symbol=^nsei;…` which looks very wrong.  You might want to check those variables.
3. error in string “innerHTML” @" – where you inserted D1 in the string.

Use the web-browser's console.log(string) console/debugger feature to test your objects and variables when in doubt (F12 to bring up the console/dev-tools in most browsers)

---

```
<div id="looknorth"></div>
<script language='javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ln(){
//var D11=String($('select[name=D1]').val());
var D11=String(D1.value),
    text = '<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D'+D11+';range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>';
//try { console.log(D11); } catch(err) { window.alert(String(D11)); }
//$('div#looknorth').html(text);
document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML=text;
}
</script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1  width="400">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#123742; font-size:12 ; font-weight:bold">
<font color="#FFFFFF">Compounding</font>
<td>&nbsp;<br />
<select name="D1" id="D1">
<option value="^nsei">Annually</option>
<option value="^bsen">Half Yearly</option>
</select>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ALIGN="center">
<input type=button style="background-color:#123742; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:15" name=calculate value=Calculate onClick=ln();>
</table>
```

;)

Comment: should i add these lines to code ... //try { console.log(D11); } catch(err) { window.alert(String(D11)); }
//$('div#looknorth').html(text);

Comment: the try block was for debugging.  I'm used to jquery, so I left in my testing-commented in case it's useful.

Comment: can any one rectify the code and help me.. as i am totally confused

Comment: when you press calculate, with the second option `^bsen`, no chart is generated.  The above code generates a graph for the code you seem to want when the 'anually' option is selected.

Comment: thanks @tfw   now it is working. you can see it live on http://rupeeinvest.com/866/testing/

Comment: i instead of drop down menu i enter many such symbol and name in a database and let people search entering part of name and get related results then click on one to get that chart displayed. how is that possible doyou have any idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="looknorth"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function ln(){
    D1 = document.getElementsByName("D1")[0]
    D11=parseFloat(D1.value);
    document.getElementById('looknorth').innerHTML='<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D'+D11+';range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>';
}
</script>
<table border=1 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1  width="400">
<tr>
<td style="background-color:#123742; font-size:12 ; font-weight:bold">
<font color="#FFFFFF">Compounding</font>
<td>&nbsp;<br />
<select name="D1">
<option value="^nsei">Annually</option>
<option value="^bsen">Half Yearly</option>
</select>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" ALIGN="center">
<input type=button style="background-color:#123742; color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; font-size:15" name="calculate" value="Calculate" onClick='ln()'>
```

​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

You had some mismatched quotes around the innerHTML line. As well, you never defined what D1 was in your javascript so when you asked for D1.value, it didn't know what you wanted.

Comment: still giving a error object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: some error seems to be here -     D1 = document.getElementsByName("D1")[0]

Comment: works for me on both Chrome and Firefox (I don't have access to IE). Have you tried adding an ID to the D1 select and using that? Like D1 = document.getElementById("D1"); and the select is <select name="D1" id="D1">

Comment: what chart it shows of NaN when error in data the variable gives you answer as Nan which is a yahoo ticker, although the chart is displayed it is not intented result

Comment: 1. It is `document.getElementsByTagName("D1")[0];`, not `document.getElementsByName("D1")[0];` 2. No need to use `parseFloat()` here because _^nsei_ or _^bsen_ do not contain numeric values

Comment: now it is working. you can see it live on rupeeinvest.com/866/testing

Answer (score 0):

There are few problems in your code:

1. JS does not know that *D1* is the name of your html select control
   unless you define that.
2. Improper usage of single and double quotes while setting the inner html of *looknorth*.
3. *parseFloat* expects a string that contains numeric values but you
   pass *^nsei* for instance, which is invalid.

Replace JS function with this:

```
function ln(){
    var D1 = document.getElementsByTagName("D1")[0];
    var D11 = D1.value;
    var lknorth = document.getElementById('looknorth');
    lknorth.innerHTML= '<embed bgcolor="#dbdbd3" flashvars="lcId=1169793726234&amp;state=symbol%3D' + D11 + ';range=1d;indicator=ema(13,34,55)+macd+rsi+stochasticfast;charttype=candlestick;crosshair=on;ohlcvalues=0;logscale=on;source=undefined" loop="false" menu="false" name="BANKNIFTY" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" src="http://us.js2.yimg.com/us.yimg.com/i/us/fi/yfc/swf/flashchart_1.18.swf" style="height: 775px; width: 550px" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="opaque"></embed>';
}
```